# How to create new mailing list using Mailchimp API v.3 and get its id?

Tags: mailchimp, mailing-list

I have never used Mailchimp API and I'm wondering if it someone could show me, through example, how to create a new list using this [endpoint](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/lists-collection)? And how would I later be able to get the id of this list (using only list name), so I can add subscribers to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using PHP and cURL:

```
<?php

    $apikey = '<api-key>'; // replace with your API key
    $dc = '<data-center>'; // replace with your data center

    $data = array( // the information for your new list--not all is required
        "name" => $name,
        "contact" => array (
            "company" => $company,
            "address1" => $address1,
            "address2 => $address2,
            "city" => $city,
            "state" => $state,
            "zip" => $zip,
            "country" => $country,
            "phone" => $phone
        ),
        "permission_reminder" => $permission_reminder,
        "use_archive_bar" => $archive_bars,
        "campaign_defaults" => array(
            "from_name" => $from_name,
            "from_email" => $from_email,
            "subject" => $subject,
            "language" => $language
        ),
        "notify_on_subscribe" => $notify_subs,
        "notify_on_unsubscribe" => $notify_unsubs,
        "email_type_option" => $type,
        "visibility" => $visibility
    );
    $data = json_encode($data); // API requires JSON objects
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$dc.".api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/"); // ../lists/ URL to create new list resource
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREQUEST, true); // declare request is POST type
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // set POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:".$apikey); // HTML Basic Auth
    $output = curl_exec($ch); // execute and capture response
    curl_close($ch); 
    print_r($output); // display API response

?>
```

For a neat way to get a feel for the API, I highly recommend playing around in the [MailChimp API Playground](https://us4.api.mailchimp.com/playground/).

Comment: To follow on, this won't allow you to get the ID of the list later by name -- that's not possible. OP will want to save the list ID themselves.

Comment: Thank you! This cleared up a lot of stuff. And thanks for the tip about Playground.